# Set enum from dropdownlist

Tags: c#

I have a property on my customer object, say gender, based on an enum.

How do I set the enum property on the object based on a `dropdownlist.selectedValue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of Enum names using something like this:

```
string[] genderList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(gender));
```

from there, just populate the drop down list

to parse it back to the enum type...

```
Gender gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), ddl.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male = 0,
    Female
}

Gender gender = (Gender)dropdownlist.selectedValue
```

The values of dropdown list can be 0,1 or Male,Female.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Enum.Parse` It takes the type and the string, or you can make your own converter